# How to return promise that will resolve with the result of several functions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm developing a jQuery plugin, which pretends to translate elements on the page, automatically depending on the user's browser language. Translations will be stored in .json files.

When you call the plugin, you pass a package name (or an Array of them) and then it will try to load the language file in the following way:

- If the browser's language is simple, for example `'en'` and you only have indicated a package, it will try to load the following: `packageName-en.json`
- If the browser's language is composed, for example 'en-US' it will try to load the same as before but with: `packageName-en.json` **AND** `packageName-en-US.json`
- If more than one package is indicated, it will try to follow one of the two previous path for each package.

So, in the plugin I have this:

```
$.fn.Translator = function(pkg, options){
    Translator.initialize(pkg, options).done(function(){
        return this.each(Translator.translate);
     });            
};
```

So, somewhere in my initialize function, I have this:

```
loadLanguages : function(){
    $.each(self.options.packages,function(i, pkg){

    });
}
```

Which will call this function :

```
getLanguage : function(pkg, language){
    var self = this, url;
    if (self.options.path)
        url = self.options.path + '/';
    url += [pkg, language].join('-');

    return $.ajax ({
        url : url,
        dataType : "json",
        cache : self.options.cache
    });
}
```

The problem is that since that function will be called probably multiple times, I don't know how to make `initialize` to return a promise which will be resolved once ALL of the functions have been called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you accepted an answer already but there is a much simpler way: use [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

```
function loadLanguages () {
    return $.when.apply( $, $.map( self.options.packages, function( pkg ) {
        return getLanguage(pkg, language);
    }) );
}
```

Comment: Though I accepted an answer I think yours is better. That's the sort of solution I was looking for and the other way seemed kinda hackish. Thank you very much Julian :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you can create a dummy Deferrer (baseDfr) and return the dummy as result of `initialize()`. The idea here is to call `baseDfr.resolve()` when all `getLanguage()` calls are done. We keep track of the number of `getLanguage()` calls that are done using a counter. When the counter reaches 0, we call `baseDfr.resolve()`.
We know when a `getLanguage()` call is done using the `then()` or `done()` method on the returned deferrer by `$.ajax` .

The code to solve this can be found below. Also, a working example (on some divs) can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/c5NBr/. Open your console to see the messages appear in correct order.

```
var packages = [];
var count = 0;
var baseDfr = $.Deferred();
var language = "en";

function resolveFunction () {
    // By using this approach it is possible to pass a 
    // parameter to this resolve function.
    return function(){
        if ( !(--count) ) {
            // Until count is 0, we won't resolve the base
            // deferrer object.
            // As long as this isn't called, the function
            // done() of initialize won't be called either.
            baseDfr.resolve();
        }     
    };
}

function getLanguage (pkg, language){
    var self = this, url;
    if (self.options.path)
        url = self.options.path + '/';
    url += [pkg, language].join('-');

    return $.ajax ({
        url : url,
        dataType : "json",
        cache : self.options.cache
    }).promise();
}

function loadLanguages () {
    $.each(self.options.packages,function(i, pkg){
        getLanguage(pkg, language).then(resolveFunction());
    });

    return baseDfr.promise();                
}

function initialize(options) {
    packages = options.packages;
    count = options.packages.length;    

    return loadLanguages();
}

var options =  {
    packages : $('div')          
};

initialize(options).done(function(){
    // This will only be called when baseDfr.resolve() is called.
    console.log("Fired all getLanguage().");
});
```